# Restroom baseboard mold removal - Replace drywall or just clean?

Tags: drywall, mold

We're renovating our 1/2 bathroom on the first floor and upon completing demo, we've uncovered a small amount of mold hiding behind the baseboards and areas where there must have been slow leaks from the toilet and sink.

I've liberally applied concrobium to all surfaces with the mold so far and am looking for advice with how to proceed. Most instances of the mold are spotty and only progressed 2-3 inches up the drywall. I don't believe it's progressed much beyond these surfaces but if prudent, I can open up the wall in a few spots to check. Do I need to cut a foot or so out and replace drywall? Or can I wipe clean, prime with a mold inhibitor paint, and plan to install new trim/paint over it?

[image: Mold by toilet]
[image: Mold by sink]
[image: Mold on opposite wall for some reason]

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion, risk tolerance, and personal health needs. We can't answer it for you. Please see the [help] for more, and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just give it a scrub.

Mold is an inhalation hazard.  If it isn't actively growing and is in a space that doesn't have air passing over it then it really isn't going to contribute to spore counts in your air.

The only reason I'd go a little bit further here would be if I were planning to replace the drywall with a paper free drywall.  Generally I use mold proof products in areas of the bathroom prone to water.  Cellular pvc baseboard, concrete board, schleuter tile board, paper free drywall, etc.  Caulk the floor to the wall and the baseboards to the floor.  Bathrooms tend to flood several times over their lifetimes so having things waterproof saves you when the inevitable water issue arrives especially if this is the lowest bathroom in the house.

Drywall can also contain asbestos so if your house is older than 1978 you have to be more careful about messing with it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not planning to replace the drywall with a paper-free version so will probably just go with the scrub option to clean it up a little and take that as an opportunity to more closely inspect the integrity of the drywall next to floor. Also the house was built 1978, but I have not encountered asbestos in all the usual locations (insulation floor tiles, etc.) so I don't believe the drywall contains it. I'm planning to install vinyl plank flooring in that room- is it best to caulk at wall joint or would that interfere with floating design?

Comment: caulk is flexible enough to move with the expansion...  LVP has limited expansion anyway.  I'd caulk.